# MVC3 project / 404 out of the box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404

I've read numerous blogs, forum questions and answers, including a bunch here on SO, but still can't figure this one out.

I'm trying to learn MVC3 by running a template MVC3 project out of the box, not changing any code, and I get a 404 error.

I try to navigate to `http://localhost:<port>/Home` and then `http://localhost:<port>/Home/Index` same results.

Literally I haven't changed anything. Here are the steps I took:

1. New Project...
2. Visual C# > Web > ASP.Net MVC 3 Web Application (give it a name and then press OK)
3. Chose "Internet Application" and check "Use HTML5 semantic markup" (OK)
4. Hit F5...

And BOOM! 404 with the usual message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /

What am I missing?

I tried adding those to the web.config files:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
```

OR

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

to no avail.

My Global.asax.cs has the original routing code:

> public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)         {
>             routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>
> ```
>       routes.MapRoute(
>           "Default", // Route name
>           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
>           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =
> ```
>
> UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults             );
>
> ```
>   }
> ```

But still the dreaded 404 when I press F5... Please help! :(

Comment: Any chance there is a dot in the name of the folder?  It is my understanding that routing can be messed up in Cassini when that is the case.

Comment: @itsmatt - I always put a dot in my folder names and have never had a problem

Comment: @Martin - that's good.  Just mentioning it because I remember reading it on an MSDN migration from 3.5 SP1 page - dealing with websites, though I re-read the OP's question again and it mentioned web application, which I think worked fine in this instance.

Comment: Are you using the built-in development web server or IIS?

Comment: There is no dot in my folder name and I'm using the built-in development web server.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your .NET Framework version in your app pool in IIS matches the version of the framework you are using.  I had this problem and it was because the app pool had defaulted to 2.0 and I was using 4.0 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller contains a "Controller" ending
for example
home - homeController
yourcontroller - yourcontollerController
Etc.